# Building Chromium Embedded on 32 bit Linux

Tags: c++, linux, google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build CEF from source.
I folowed the instructions given [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding). to download the code
But when I run : ./cef_create_projects.sh
I get the folowing output:

```
Checking CEF and Chromium revisions...

________ running '/usr/bin/python tools/check_revision.py' in '/home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3'
Using CEF revision 1274 @ http://chromiumembedded.googlecode.com/ ... /1453/cef3
Using Chromium revision 202711 @ http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/1453/src
Using .gclient file from : /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/../../.gclient
Using Chromium release http://src.chromium.org/svn/releases/27.0.1453.110

Generating CEF version header file...

________ running '/usr/bin/python tools/make_version_header.py --header include/cef_version.h --cef_version VERSION --chrome_version ../chrome/VERSION --cpp_header_dir include' in '/home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3'
File include/cef_version.h is already up to date.

Patching build configuration and source files for CEF...

________ running '/usr/bin/python tools/patcher.py --patch-config patch/patch.cfg' in '/home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3'
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/gritsettings.patch
WARNING:root:file is not patched - failed hunk: 1
WARNING:root:source file is different - ../tools/gritsettings/resource_ids
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/build.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../build/common.gypi
WARNING:root:already patched ../build/mac/strip_save_dsym
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/zlib.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/zlib/contrib/minizip/unzip.c
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/message_loop_443.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../base/message_loop.cc
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/webkit_features.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/features.gypi
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/webkit_933.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/src/WebNode.cpp
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/gyp_331.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/ninja.py
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/webkit_popups.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/src/WebViewImpl.cpp
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/src/WebViewImpl.h
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/src/ChromeClientImpl.cpp
WARNING:root:already patched ../third_party/WebKit/Source/WebKit/chromium/public/WebView.h
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/renderer_host_953.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/renderer_host/render_widget_host_view_mac.mm
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/renderer_main_642.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/renderer/renderer_main.cc
Reading patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/drag_handler_601.patch
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_gtk.cc
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_gtk.h
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_mac.h
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_mac.mm
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_win.cc
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/browser/web_contents/web_drag_dest_win.h
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/public/browser/web_contents_delegate.cc
WARNING:root:already patched ../content/public/browser/web_contents_delegate.h
Skipping patch file /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3/patch/patches/spi_webcore_364.patch

Generating CEF project files...

________ running '/usr/bin/python tools/gyp_cef cef.gyp -I cef.gypi' in '/home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3'
Using cef_dir from : /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/cef3
Using chrome_src from : /home/mchill/LDB_Workspace/Chromium/src/tools/gyp/pylib
Updating projects from gyp files...
```

Then I run ./build_projects.sh Release from inside the tools folder.
And I get the folowing error:

```
AR(target) out/Release/obj.target/skia/libskia.a
ar: out/Release/obj.target/skia/third_party/skia/src/images/SkImageDecoder_Factory.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/Release/obj.target/skia/libskia.a] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me, What is the issue here ?
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you help me how to build the source?

Comment: If you want to build from source try: (http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding).
The cef python build instructions are slightly easier to follow:http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/BuildOnLinux
Just replace the python specific stuff with the ones from the cef link

Comment: Using the automate-git.py python /path/to/automate/automate-git.py --download-dir=/path/to/download --branch=2623 --force-clean-deps to get a clean build of dependences. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding